# Apache Commons-net FTPClient, incorrect login

Tags: java, ftp-client

I am using FTPClient to connect one of our server using username/pwd. but i always i am getting 530 incorrect login info.

```
public static FTPClient connectToFTPServer() throws Exception {

    FTPClient client;
    client = new FTPClient();

    client.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
    client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new   PrintWriter(System.out)));

    client.connect(ftpHost, ftpPort);

    boolean loginSuccess = client.login("abc","abc");

    if (!loginSuccess) {
        client.logout();
        client.disconnect();
        throw new Exception("Connection could not be established with host " + ftpHost + " : " + ftpPort + " User "
                 );
    }

    //client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    client.setFileType(2);

    return client;
}     

220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
USER abc
331 Please specify the password.
PASS abc
530 Login incorrect.
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

i can able to login to same server from my putty using ssh or sftp. any one faced similar issue.

Thanks in advance

Thanks,
Ramki

Comment: you mentioned that the connection works using ssh/sftp but you are not using an FTPSClient. Also I don't know whether  client.enterLocalPassiveMode(); actually works. The javadoc says: "currently calling any connect method will reset the mode to
     * ACTIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE."

Comment: i deleted that statement. but no luck. still i see same error.
i can do ssh or sftp from my cygwin.